# Liquid Layer above Melted Chocolate

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate

Recently I was experimenting with bakers chocolate. I proceeded to add some butter and continued to mix until smooth. Afterwards, I added a small amount of whole milk and the chocolate didn't really change. Once I added more milk the consistency of the chocolate radically changed and became a lot smoother. Additionally the chocolate separated into two layers, what appeared to be a water layer and a very smooth chocolate layer.

Could someone explain what was going on? Why did the water layer form? Was it from the moisture in the milk? If I try this again, does anyone have a good method of removing the water layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blending ingredients with cocoa solids are best added at the same temperature as the chocolate. If you used cold milk the fat in the milk heated before the water content and was absorbed leaving the water to float. Although I avoid milk and use cream I have rescued both ganache & chocolate with icing sugar and/or cocoa powder adding a little at a time.